# Screen sharing with absolutely no chance of control?

Tags: security, screen-sharing

I'd like to give a presentation to other people who happen to be in the same room. I'll be running various programs and would like my screen to be visible as I work. Instead of a projector, I am wondering if I can use screen sharing. It's not clear to me if there is a way I can start such that I can be absolutely sure there is no chance of others having any control over my computer, cursor, command-line, etc. I only want to broadcast my screen to other computers' screens instead of using a big monitor or projector.

How exactly can I set up screen sharing to be sure? Are there good alternatives *within OSX?* (I don't want to have to download or install 3rd party software).

Comment: [Screen Sharing via OS X's built-in VNC](http://dssw.co.uk/reference/vnc/) is limited to one connection at a time. I presume you want to share with multiple people at the same time – is this right?

Comment: @GrahamMiln indeed you're correct - I want to "broadcast" my screen to a group (n>>1) of other people's computers in the room, as an alternative to a big screen or projector. It seems then that Screen Sharing via OSX will not work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built into OS X that allows you to share your screen with multiple people at once.

## One-to-One : Screen Sharing

[OS X's built-in Screen Sharing](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/vnc/) is limited to a one-to-one connection. Screen Sharing is based on VNC and can be limited to observation only.

## One-to-Many : Google Hangout / Skype

Consider using a [Google Hangout to share your screen](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1660627?hl=en). While it does require third party software, the use of the Chrome browser is free. This approach also ensures no-one can control your shared screen.

Alternatively, Skype group calls allow for multiple people to observe your screen.

Comment: I see, thanks! Does Google Hangout require any more 3rd party software besides Chrome? (which I loosely think of as only 2.5rd party since it's them). The drawback is that we'd need enough internet bandwidth to the room to accommodate n simultaneous transmissions of my screen - which will be silly if I play a video. Anyway, this is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: I believe everything needed for Hangout is built-into Chrome. Bandwidth may become a problem but best to try before assuming too much and adding unnecessary complexity. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

We use Skype screen sharing for group training sessions. The image quality of course is nothing like what sharing over a local connection would offer. But the viewer has no chance to touch your screen or affect your computer.

[image]

TeamViewer has similar features, much better image quality and has a free edition but the free version is non-commercial use only. Commercial licenses are prohibitively expensive except in a corporate environment (a single portable seat is about $1000).

[image]

A portable projector is looking like excellent value in comparison. A good quality full HD BenQ which you could also use to watch movies at home can be had for about $500. It would be great if Apple would enable screen broadcast in a future OS update. It seems like an obvious add. Perhaps there are DRM reasons they don't (rebroadcast of DRM content).

If motion isn't that important but image quality is you could also consider setting up automated uploads from a folder of screenshots to something like a Dropbox gallery. From there you could ask people to open the latest screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, but Skype and TeamViewer are 3rd party software and I said "*I don't want to have to download or install 3rd party software*".  I can make an exception for Chrome because I already have it and use it as my main browser.

Comment: I covered the other options including the projector. Hopefully my answer will be of use to others. Chrome is effectively third party software and uses Google services to offer you what Skype (Microsoft) and TeamViewer are offering. The only one offering a hope of any kind of privacy is TeamViewer as it's a Germany based company. Until Apple really fixes this issue (broadcast screensharing), the projector is looking awfully good.